# The clock on the emulator is not sync with the computer clock

Tags: android, clock

I working with eclipse and the emulator(android V2.2).
Each time that I am running the emulator, the date & time is not correct.
I already tried to uncheck the automatic option (in settings => Date & Time) and 
set the date & time manually but unfortunately on the next day when I run the emulator 
again, the date & time is not correct.

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the TimeZone for the emulator by setting up a 'Run Configuration' for the app.

In eclipse go to Run|Run Configurations...

On the Target tab scroll to the bottom (scroll bar on right) and add `-timezone America/Toronto` (or your timezone) to the `Additional Emulator Command Line Options` text box.

Time zones are in [zoneinfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zoneinfo_time_zones) format.

Comment: I added -timezone Eastern to target in Run configurations but still the date & time is not shown correctly, do I need then to change manually again the date & time in the settings(like in my first post)?

Comment: is it out by a random amount or an even hour?

Comment: I think the problem is when I am starting the emulator it won`t sync with the computer clock.
The date & time is the same as I set it yesterday with difference of the minutes

Comment: I have been experimenting with the settings.  first off I have edited the above to reflect the `zoneinfo format` for timezones.  Secondly if I set manual date and time settings the '-timezone' flag is ignored.  Try setting the emulator to 'Automatic' time setting then kill and reload the emulator with an appropriate timezone from the above link.

Comment: I did this steps:
1) I changed the setting to Automatic(in date & time section)
2) I added this -timezone Eastern in run config =>target => additional Emulator command line
3) closed the emulator and the eclipse
4) start the emulator
The date is 09/05/2012 and the time is 1:28 but the correct date & time is 20/05/2012 09:25 (I am living in Israel)

Comment: Your timezone should be `-timezone Asia/Jerusalem`.  You only need to restart the emulator not eclipse.